# Scroll event only fires once unless you scroll to the opposite direction

Tags: javascript, scroll, direction

I'm trying to trigger an horizontal scroll on, well... scroll.

Nothing that fancy here, but for some reason, the scroll event only fires once, then nothing for a few seconds, unless you scroll in the opposite direction.

Usually the problem is pretty much the opposite, preventing scroll from firing again and again. I'm a bit clueless here.

```
var self = this;
$(window).on('scroll', function (e) {
 if (!self.scrolling) {
    self.scrolling = true;
    self.removeActive();
    self.index++;
    self.addActive();

    setTimeout(function(){
        self.scrolling = false;
    }, self.trsd + 1);
 }
});
```

[Full code](http://codepen.io/isthatcentered/pen/gpVRqQ).

Comment: maybe since you are at the limit of the page you arent really scrolling so its only logical that if you do scroll (the oposite direction) it will trigger

Comment: Nice! I misunderstood the behavior of the scroll event.

You were totally right, I just changed my event for mousewheel, no problem anymore :)

Thank you !